# Questions about the integration of videos via tiktok video connection in the mobile APP

Tags: ios

Our company hopes to add a new function to our mobile APP, which can obtain videos through the URL of tiktok videos and upload them to our own APP.

But I do not know how to complete this work, I did not find any related library on the Internet.I want someone to tell me how to do this, or which library to use.Many thanks to you!!!!